# "Worksheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible" Changes the Active Tab

Tags: vba, excel

Why is Excel changing the active sheet with my code below, and how can I (elegantly/properly) stop it from doing so?

I have a workbook with many tabs and am using VBA to filter the visible sheets based on my selection(s) in a listbox. Pausing the program after it shows a hidden sheet, using either a breakpoint or `Application.Wait (Now)`, makes everything run right, but this strikes me as bad practice and would prefer an alternative. I cannot reproduce the error in a new workbook with many blank tabs, and removing the `Application.ScreenUpdating` call at the start and finish does not change my results either, so I assume it's taking Excel too long to process each of my sheets and this is causing this strange error.

This bug is annoying because if I accidentally choose the wrong item in the listbox, Excel switches to another sheet and I have to manually click back to the sheet which contains that listbox to fix my selection.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each mySheet In Worksheets
    Select Case mySheet.Name
        Case "Cost Overview", "Project Eng.", "Mfg Development", "Labor Summary", "S.O.P.", "MFGD Time", "MFGD Group", "HowTo", ChrW(&H21BB)
            'These sheets are always visible, so do nothing
        Case Else
            mySheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'or xlSheetHidden or xlSheetVeryHidden or xlSheetVisible
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Application.Wait (Now) 'WITHOUT THIS SLIGHT DELAY, ACTIVE TAB CHANGES
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    End Select

Next
For i = 1 To Worksheets("Labor Summary").ListBoxes("ListBoxForSlicers").ListCount

    'The category names are "Div 1" and "Div 2", referenced here and in the ListBox from ColorIndexTable'
    CategoryName = Application.WorksheetFunction.index(Range("ColorIndexTable[Category]"), i)
    CategorySelected = Worksheets("Labor Summary").ListBoxes("ListBoxForSlicers").Selected(i)

    If CategorySelected Then
        Select Case CategoryName
            Case "Div 1"
                For Each mySheet In Worksheets
                    Select Case mySheet.Name
                        Case "Cost Overview", "Project Eng.", "Mfg Development", "Labor Summary", "S.O.P.", "MFGD Time", "MFGD Group", "HowTo", ChrW(&H21BB)
                            'These sheets are always visible, so do nothing
                        Case "MFGC", "CUT", "ASSM", "HOT MELT", "POT", "MOLD", "POST-OP", "MARK", "PACK", "PPRNT", "TEST"
                            'These sheets ought to be visible, so do nothing
                        Case Else
                            mySheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
                    End Select
                Next

            Case "Div 2"
                For Each mySheet In Worksheets
                    Select Case mySheet.Name
                        Case "Cost Overview", "Project Eng.", "Mfg Development", "Labor Summary", "S.O.P.", "MFGD Time", "MFGD Group", "HowTo", ChrW(&H21BB)
                            'These sheets are always visible, so do nothing
                        Case "CUT", "ASSM", "TEST", "POST-OP", "PACK"
                            'These sheets ought to be visible, so do nothing
                        Case Else
                            mySheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
                    End Select
                Next
        End Select
    End If

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also cannot duplicate the error ... but you might try this in the workbook that does generate the error ...

```
Set oldActive = ActiveSheet
mySheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
oldActive.Activate
```

Comment: Now the only question is, how many tabs do I need to be processing before this becomes faster than adding `Application.Wait (Now)` to each loop? I don't know the answer, but I do like your solution since it's much clearer what problem it's solving, and ought to work no matter how slow (or fast?) the computer is.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the famous case of the need for the very much not recommended `DoEvents`.

It basically lets Windows process all the messages in queue that are waiting for execution.

It is therefore usually not recommended in bigger applications, but does miracles in simple VBA macros.

Try this:

```
    Case Else
        mySheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible 
        DoEvents
End Select
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's just `DoEvents` not `Application.DoEvents`!

Comment: Unfortunately adding `DoEvents` does not fix the problem, so I guess I won't be using this very much not recommended function anyways :\

Comment: @Rory My bad, fixed. Thanks.